# How to transfer sharedpreferences file from internal storage to external storage?

Tags: java, android, xml, file, sharedpreferences

How to copy `sharedpreferences` to external storage keeping `xml format`, so later it could be possible to share preferences.

Tried to read `sharedpreferences` and save as a `string` into file, created `JSON` type of a `string`, but I need an `xml`. Thought of traversing through app's internal storage and copy file and put it in external storage, but that could be too complex.

Just really would want to know if there is an easy and sensible way to transfer `sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code,

```
SharedPreferences preferences=this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.application", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String,?> keys = preferences.getAll();
Properties properties = new Properties();
for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue().toString();
    properties.setProperty(key, value);      
}
try {
    File file = new File("externalPreferences.xml");
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    properties.storeToXML(fileOut, "External Preferences");
    fileOut.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and to retrive use this,

```
try {
    File file = new File("externalPreferences.xml");
    FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.loadFromXML(fileInput);
    fileInput.close();

    Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
        String value = properties.getProperty(key);
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**NOTE** You can handle only String type preferences with this code,

Comment: It works, but now I'll have to redesign other parts of code parsing to integer type, because everything is a string.

Comment: Sure, Please don't forget to share that with us,

Comment: change move editor.commit(); outside of the loop. Don't need to commit at each value.

Answer (score 0):

for load shared preference from file try this

```
private fun loadSharedPreferences(src: File, sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences) {
    try{
      var fileInput : FileInputStream = FileInputStream(src)
      val properties : Properties = Properties()
      properties.loadFromXML(fileInput)
      fileInput.close()
      val enuKeys = properties.keys()
      val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
      while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()){
        var key = enuKeys.nextElement() as String
        var value = properties.getProperty(key)
        when {
          key.contains("string",true) -> {    //in my case the key of a String contain "string"
            editor.putString(key, value)
          }
          key.contains("int", true) -> {    //in my case the key of a Int contain "int"
            editor.putInt(key, value.toInt())
          }
          key.contains("boolean", true) -> {  // //in my case the key of a Boolean contain "boolean"
            editor.putBoolean(key, value.toBoolean())
          }
        }

        editor.apply();
      }
    }catch ( e : FileNotFoundException) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( e : IOException) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```