# How can I restore data from instant app to installed app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

## Keep user state after app installation

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/ux-best-practices.html#keep_user_state_after_app_installation

I want to use the data stored in instant app, after installation full app.
Does anyone know it?

Comment: can you provide what user state you want to restore? You can write your user info in persistent storage, later when you open your app, you read it again.

Comment: @UddhavGautam Thank you for your comment.
The data I want to restore are images downloaded in instant app.

Comment: If you save that images to internal storage, you can always access it from the installable app.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**   They’ve again updated the [Instant Apps FAQ](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html) on how to do this.

> For devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, the instant
>   app's data is transferred automatically when the APK installation
>   begins, if the installed app is configured to use targetSandboxVersion
>   2.
>
> For installed apps not configured to use targetSandboxVersion 2, or
>   devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower, please consider
>   using the Cookie API (Sample) or Storage API (Sample) to transfer the
>   data.

For Oreo 8.0 and higher, it should be automatically handled.

But for 7.0 and below, you've got 2 options (#1 is recommended):

1. [PackageManagerCompat#setInstantAppCookie()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/PackageManagerCompat#setInstantAppCookie(byte[])), the cookie has a size limit, but it is the simplest and most suitable for shared preferences.
2. [InstantAppsClient#getInstantAppData()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/InstantAppsClient#getInstantAppData()), creates a ZIP of the data that you'll have to extract and parse once it's moved over to the installed-app side, a bit more complicated.

The FAQ lists a sample for each option:

- [googlesamples/android-instant-apps/cookie-api](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/cookie-api)
- [googlesamples/android-instant-apps/storage-api](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/storage-api)

The Storage API/ZIP sample does not show you how to parse the ZIP files and what file type/format to expect from SharedPreferences files, so you'll have to implement that yourself, but here are some related posts:

- [How to read file from ZIP using InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869228/how-to-read-file-from-zip-using-inputstream)
- [How to transfer sharedpreferences file from internal storage to external storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917809/how-to-transfer-sharedpreferences-file-from-internal-storage-to-external-storage)